# Как узнать ID пользователя ВКонтакте, заходившего к нам на сайт?

Tags: javascript, вконтакте

Здравствуйте. Как узнать id пользователя, заходившего к нам на сайт без участия самого пользователя?
Т.е. при заходе пользователя на наш сайт асинхронно с нашего сайта на сайт ВКонтакте отправляется запрос, а возвращается ID пользователя, зашедшего на сайт.
Спасибо.

Comment: Думаю, что никак. Ответьте для себя на вопрос: какие данные сайт будет посылать в запросе к вконтакте, чтобы идентифицировать пользователя, и отдаст ли вконтакте вам Id пользователя по его IP?

Comment: Как нарушить privacy посетителя сайта? Надеюсь, что никак. Если и есть какой-то путь, о нём надо немедленно сообщить ВК, чтобы они его закрыли.

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/238565/
рекоммендую копать отсюда

Comment: "Вы не авторизованы ВКонтакте" при этом я авторизирован

Answer (score 6):

Для тех пользователей ВК, кто установил одно из приложений, чьим доменом значится тот же, что у вашей фиш-страницы.

1. Нужен только id приложения, секрет не потребуется.
2. См. раздел [OpenAPI](https://vk.com/dev/openapi) – там есть пример кода "Пример авторизации через Open API":

   ```
   <script src="//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

   <div id="login_button" onclick="VK.Auth.login(authInfo);"></div>

   <script language="javascript">
       VK.init({
           apiId: ВАШ_API_ID
       });
       function authInfo(response) {
           if (response.session) {
               alert('user: '+response.session.mid);
           } else {
               alert('not auth');
           }
       }
       VK.Auth.getLoginStatus(authInfo);
       VK.UI.button('login_button');
   </script>
   ```

Уже при заходе на страницу выведет алертом ВК id, если пользователь ранее установил это приложение, согласившись дать ему доступ к своей базовой информации. Можно вместо алерта отправить его ajax'ом на ваш сервер статистики.

Comment: Алертом выводит ID только того, кто создал это приложение. Если зайти с другого аккаунта, всегда 'not auth'.

Comment: конечно, это состояние по умолчанию

Comment: Вы пробовали с другого аккаунта протестировать?

Comment: @Максим147, вы правы, my fault! )) Проверял на разных аккаунтах, все из которых уже устанавливали когда-то используемое приложение – и давали тогда разрешение на доступ к своим личным данным!

Действует только на тех, кто установил себе приложение, чей домен совпадает с фишинговой страницей. Что заметно сужает охват : )

Answer (score 2):

Собственно, нужно, чтобы пользователь авторизовался на сайте через ВК, а там уже в ответе от ВК будет ID пользователя. 
А так вряд ли еще что поможет.